# How to check if number1, number2, and number3 is equal to a, b and c but not necessarily in this order

Tags: c++

I have a game that generates three random numbers and you have to guess them. I don't know how to check whether these 3 numbers are the same as these generated. I have written this but I know it's really bad and not readable. I looked for something better but didn't find anything. Is there any way to make it better and more readable?

```
bool Guess(int number1, int number2, int number3)
{
    int guess1, guess2, guess3;

    std::cout << "Enter three numbers separated by spaces: ";

    std::cin >> guess1 >> guess2 >> guess3;

    if (guess1 == number1)
    {
        if (guess2 == number2)
        {
            if (guess3 == number3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (guess2 == number3)
        {
            if (guess3 == number2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (guess2 == number1)
    {
        if (guess1 == number2)
        {
            if (guess3 == number3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (guess1 == number3)
        {
            if (guess3 == number2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (guess3 == number1)
    {
        if (guess2 == number2)
        {
            if (guess1 == number3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(guess1 == number2)
        {
            if (guess2 == number3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is the fragment how I generate these numbers

```
int GenerateNumber(int level)
{
    if (level == 1)
    {
        return (rand() % 2) + level; // if level is one than number range is from 1 to 2
    }
    else
    {
        return (rand() % level) + level; // else number range is from level to (level * 2) - 1
    }
}

int a = GenerateNumber(level);
int b = GenerateNumber(level);
int c = GenerateNumber(level);
```

Comment: Can you include the code where `number1`, `number2`, and `number3` are assigned?  Also, your logic is not clear to me.  Are you trying to check if all three numbers match, in any order?

Comment: Totally in general: Don't write code like `if(condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`, just write `return condition;` instead...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have included it. Yes, I want to check if this numbers match in any order

Comment: Be aware that `rand() % maximum` doesn't produce good distributions. Better is `rand() * maximum/(RAND_MAX + 1)`, provided no overflow occurs. Or you use [new C++ random facilities](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, then change the order to something that makes it easy to do.  To do that, you can put the guesses and numbers in separate arrays, sort them and then compare.  You can make this whole process even easier by using a [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)/[`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset) to do all of this work for you.  That would look like

```
bool Guess(int number1, int number2, int number3)
{
    int guess1, guess2, guess3;

    std::cout << "Enter three numbers separated by spaces: ";

    std::cin >> guess1 >> guess2 >> guess3;

    return std::multiset<int>{guess1, guess2, guess3} == std::multiset<int>{number1, number2, number3};
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that the file includes the header `set`

Comment: @Aconcagua Yep.  I had updated the link but not the text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest the following solution as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool Guess( int number1, int number2, int number3 )
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    std::array<int, N> target = { number1, number2, number3 };
    std::sort( std::begin( target ), std::end( target ) );

    std::array<int, N> guess;

    std::cout << "Enter three numbers separated by spaces: ";

    std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ), N, std::begin( guess ) );

    std::sort( std::begin( guess ), std::end( guess ) );

    return target == guess;
}

int main() 
{
    int n1 = 3, n2 = 1, n3 = 2;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Guess( n1, n2, n3 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter three numbers separated by spaces: 1 2 3
true
```

Instead of the call pf the algorithm `std::copy_n` you can just use the following statement

```
std::cin >> guess[0] >> guess[1] >> guess[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much like the sorting approach – but if you don't have duplicates in your reference numbers, you could alternatively do the following:

```
return (number1 == guess1 || number1 == guess2 || number1 == guess3)
    && (number2 == guess1 || number2 == guess2 || number2 == guess3)
    && (number3 == guess1 || number3 == guess2 || number3 == guess3);
```

Totally simple...

This *won't* work, though, if you *do* have duplicates, as you'd succeed guessing 1, 1, 1 with 1, 2, 3 as well...

**Edit:** The algorithm you use *currently* (question revision 3) *does* produce duplicates. If do not intend to change that, this solution is not suitable!